# SSHTunnelForwarder - "IP is not a string (NoneType)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to use SSHTunnelForwarder. I receive an error "IP is not a string (NoneType)". If I understand correctly, that means the host variable I'm passing is of type NoneType and needs to be String type. Printing out the variables type shows that it is of type string: <class 'str'>.

I've generalized the code in question. See below:

```
def connectToClient(client):
    key, host = getClientInfo(client)
    # Both of the below print statements return <class 'str'>
    print(type(key))
    print(type(host))

    try:
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ssh_username = "username",
            ssh_private_key = key,
            remote_bind_address = (host, 22)) as server:
                # Do stuff here

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exception
```

Stack Trace (edited to hide file system info and .py file name. Also testing with 0.0.0.0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/myPythonFile.py", line 83, in connectToClient
    remote_bind_address = ('0.0.0.0', 22)) as server:
  File "/path/to/file/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 908, in __init__
    check_host(self.ssh_host)
  File "/path/to/file/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 79, in check_host
    type(host).__name__
AssertionError: IP is not a string (NoneType)
```

I'd like to point out that even if I replace the host variable with a string holding an IP (i.e. '127.0.0.1'), I still receive the same error.

Perhaps I'm making a simple mistake. Any ideas?

Edit: Fix formatting and add stack trace

Comment: Would you please add your whole stack-trace and add result of the `print()` statements?

Comment: I've added the stack trace. As mentioned, the print statements both return <class 'str'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an argument. See the [example](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
In practice, you are calling `SSHTunnelForwarder` without the keyword argument `ssh_address_or_host` which represents the IP and optionally the port number of the remote host.
Indeed, you are confusing the meaning of `remote_bind_address` using it as it is the `ssh_address_or_host`.

When the method will check for the host part relative to the IP will not find a string, but None and here comes the exception. See the [code](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py).

Comment: This looks like it fixed the issue, thank you. Do you have a quick explanation of difference between remote_bind_address and ssh_address_or_host. One holds the hostname (and possibly a port number) of remote machine and the other holds the IP and port number of the remote machine? Why do I need both?

Comment: You can have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236865/what-does-bind-address-mean-in-ssh-port-forwarding and https://superuser.com/questions/1285009/ssh-gateway-how-to-understand-ssh-l-when-remote-comes-first for good explanations of the` ssh -L` option.